# How to find if a value is NaN in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to modify dataframe when value in column = NaN.
When I try this solution:

```
if df['columnx'].isnull().values.any():
    df['columnx'] = df['columnz']
```

all the columns seem to be converted, not only when meeting the criteria of NaN value.

This is what I get if I print the columnx values:

```
1  12345
2  12346
3  12347
4  NaN
5  NaN
6  NaN
```

When df['columnz'] has:

```
4   12355
5   12356
6   12357
```

I only want the the:

```
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
```

So I can convert

```
df['columnx'] = df['columnz']
```

So that I have df['columnx']:

```
1   12345
2   12346
3   12347
4   12355
5   12356
6   12357
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.where`

```
df['columnx'] = np.where(df['columnx'].isnull(),df['columnz'],df['columnx'])
```

Comment: great! that's what I needed. Thanks!